# Why is "String.class" necessary here?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Given this code:

```
dm.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
    @Nullable String s) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        arrayList.add(value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why we use `String.class` in the method

```
 dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

What is the purpose of it? I am using it when getting data from Firebase. My code is working fine. Just want to learn the meaning.

Comment: String.class means your data is of string type.

Comment: `String.class` is a way of referring to the `String` type. Presumably `getValue(String.class)` means "get me a value of type `String`"

Comment: @khelwood Post that as an answer! :)

Comment: @LeeWhite No, I don't know what `DataSnapshop` is. It's only a guess.

Comment: DataSnapShot is Kindof JSON version of data stored in firebase database. @khelwood

Comment: what is the meaning of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: @ALIKHAN its means there is a change in data and update your changes to reflect on UI.

Comment: welcome @ALIKHAN if you need anyhelp do let me know

Comment: Edit your Question to describe and link to the library you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [Javadoc for `DataSnapshot`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)):

> **`public T getValue (Class<T> valueType)`**
>
> This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple constraints:
>
> 1. The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> 2. The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

So because this method can return any type of class as it is a generic method, the type of class the method returns has to be specified as a parameter. In this case `value` is a `String`, so you need to pass `String.class` into the method to get a `String` back out.

Although in this instance, because a `String` is returned, you can alternatively use the parameter-less `getValue()` method and cast the result like so:

```
String value = (String) getValue();
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()):

> getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The possible types returned are:
>
> - Boolean
> - String
> - Long
> - Double
> - Map
> - List

Comment: thanks, Michael. I have another question I you don't mind.

Comment: what is the meaning of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @ALIKHAN No worries, if this has helped then please accept this answer by clicking the ✔ icon underneath the score. As for `notifyDataSetChanged()`, that tells the list adapter that its data has been modified, and should therefore update what is shown in the list on screen.

Comment: If you're ever in doubt, just look up the method name in your favourite search engine and it'll lead to the documentation.

Comment: It's actually [`getValue(Class)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) in the OP's question, not [`getValue(GenericTypeIndicator)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator%3CT%3E)). A class is not an instance of `GenericTypeIndicator`.

Comment: Thanks for your help really appreciate it.